# Oracle SQL Developer (4.0.2.15) command line (sdcli) bind variables

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Trying to run user defined reports in sql developer from the sdcli command line.

How do I pass a bind variable to the sql, documentation is not clear?

eg. Very simple sql where "pin" is the bind variable:

```
select
  *
from
  sasso
where
  sasso.assoc_id = :pin
```

Command line:

```
sdcli reports generate -report "User Detail" -db Wyong_Prod -FILE "C:\temp\user.html" -bind pin = 7292
```

Does not work, sdcli returns "success" but report contains no data, ie. bind variable does not work. (7292 is a number and definitely exists - works in sql developer gui).

cheers,
Justin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working for me

c:\Program Files\Oracle\sqldev\4.2\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin>sdcli reports generate -report untappd -db hr -file C:\users\jdsmith\untappd.html -bind RATING=3
Command Completed.

[image]

That's got a bind for :RATING, which I ran at 3

Then I called from the CLI

```
c:\Program Files\Oracle\sqldev\4.2\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin>sdcli reports generate -report untappd -db hr -file C:\users\jdsmith\untappd.html -bind RATING=3
Command Completed.
```

Opened the report...exact same data

[image]

I know it's 'working' because my report wouldn't run w/o a value supplied to the :BIND as I have no default set.

The bind's could be case-sensitive (java!?!), so make sure how it's set in yourr report matches how you call it on the CLI

Comment: Thanks heaps Jeff for the example. it was just the damn spaces either side of the = in the bind expression that did me in! arrggh!